# Skip a few rows when parsing Excel using OleDb

Tags: excel, oledb

I chose OleDb as a method of reading data from Excel, one of my problems on parsing the Excel is this:

I want to skip a few rows from the file (let's call them a header..) - there are merged cells there and other stuff I need to ignore, I found this syntax:

```
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$a4:c]',
```

specifying "a4" - the left corner of the header row, and "c" - the right most column where the data is ..how ever this is not OK to me as I do not know the exact number of columns with data I need to parse ...Is there another way of accomplishing this ?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use a little code to find the bottom right cell?

Comment: Well...no particular reason, I checked & it works, it seems that I just read somewhere that Ole would take the first row to calculate the columns number, which seems to be incorrect ....

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A4:end]'`

Answer (score 4):

you can take all rows in a dataTable and then

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> newRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(1);
DataTable  dt2 = newRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

dt2 now contains all rows but the first.